# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i was trying to get the sum of the row items in a datagridview
this is my code

```
 Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click


    If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then
        Dim RegFee As Integer = 0
        Dim MisFee As Integer = 0
        Dim TuiFee As Integer = 0
        Dim PtcaFee As Integer = 0
        Dim CompFee As Integer = 0

        For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            RegFee += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(4).Value)
            MisFee += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(5).Value)
            TuiFee += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(6).Value)
            PtcaFee += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(7).Value)
            CompFee += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(8).Value)

        Next
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Registration Fee", RegFee)
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Miscellaneous Fee", MisFee)
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Tuition Fee", TuiFee)
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add("PTCA Fee", PtcaFee)
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Computer Fee", CompFee)

    End If
End Sub
```

but i'm having an error:
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
can you help me???

Comment: if `Rows(index).Cells(N).Value` is nothing in the db, DBNull, it cant be added to anything like `RegFee`, `TuiFee` etc.  you need to test for DBNull first

Comment: @Plutonix how???can you give a sample code???

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5(v=vs.90).aspx you should also take the time to accept some of the many answers you get if/when they help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IsDbNull` like this:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then
    Dim RegFee As Integer = 0
    Dim MisFee As Integer = 0
    Dim TuiFee As Integer = 0
    Dim PtcaFee As Integer = 0
    Dim CompFee As Integer = 0
    For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        RegFee += If(IsDbNull(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(4).Value), 0,   Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(4).Value))
        'Do the same for the rest
    Next
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Registration Fee", RegFee)
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Miscellaneous Fee", MisFee)
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Tuition Fee", TuiFee)
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add("PTCA Fee", PtcaFee)
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Computer Fee", CompFee)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: OK. Try again. Added the `.Value`

Comment: @Steve i'm still new in programming can you give me a sample code?i will really appreciate it :)

Comment: @KayeSantos - Try again. I've added the `.Value`. This should work: `RegFee += If(IsDbNull(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(4).Value), 0,   Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(4).Value))`