# System.InvalidCastException: 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Have checked the other solutions [Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098646/object-cannot-be-cast-from-dbnull-to-other-types), [Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360440/object-cannot-be-cast-from-dbnull-to-other-types), though they did not help in my case.

Sample Code:

```
private void DisplayClosedIncidents()
{
    lstIncidents.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select an incident--", "None"));
    foreach (DataRowView row in incidentsTable)
    {
        Incident incident = new Incident();
        incident.IncidentID = Convert.ToInt32(row["IncidentID"]);
        incident.ProductCode = row["ProductCode"].ToString();
        incident.DateClosed = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateClosed"]);
        incident.Title = row["Title"].ToString();
        lstIncidents.Items.Add(new ListItem(incident.CustomerIncidentDisplay(), incident.IncidentID.ToString()));
    }
}
```

The line in the code causing the error is
`incident.DateClosed = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateClosed"]);`

I understand why I'm encountering the error (the value of DateClosed (format is standard yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) for this row of my DataSource is DBnull, which can't be converted to a DateTime.

I understand I can use default values in the DataSource to resolve the error. Is this the most simple method to resolve? Is there another method I can use to omit this field for the row (keep the null value while retaining the other fields that are not null)?

Comment: You will have to explicitly check for DBNull, something like `row["DateClosed"] is DBNull ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your pointer, it was helpful. I solved my problem like so:

if (row["DateClosed"].GetType() == typeof(DBNull))
                {incident.DateClosed = Convert.ToDateTime("0001-01-01 00:00:00");}